Recommendations in Elasticsearch
There is a product database; the popularity value for products is periodically calculated. An index has been built in ES, there is sorting by popularity value.
There is a task to screw up a recommendation system. The recommendation system for each user_id produces N recommended products with a recommendation value from 0 to 1.
It is required to display products for each user in this way: first those with popularity >A (top products) sorted by popularity, then recommended for the user (sorted), then all the rest sorted by popularity.
How can this sorting be implemented at the ES level? How to put user recommendations there?
How can this sorting be implemented at the ES level? How to put user recommendations there?

Hey, if you can share a picture or any example with expected result it would be easier to help you

Products could be sorted by the dis_max query
Mapping
PUT /product_popularity
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "title": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "popularity": {
                "type": "double"
            },
            "recommended_for_users": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "user_id": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "recommendation_value": {
                        "type": "double"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Documents. Popularity is from 0 to 1 as well
POST /product_popularity/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"title":"speaker","popularity":0.8,"recommended_for_users":[{"user_id":"A","recommendation_value":0.2},{"user_id":"B","recommendation_value":0.7}]}
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{"title":"fridge","popularity":0.1,"recommended_for_users":[{"user_id":"A","recommendation_value":0.9},{"user_id":"B","recommendation_value":0.1}]}
{"create":{"_id":3}}
{"title":"table","popularity":0.2,"recommended_for_users":[{"user_id":"B","recommendation_value":0.4},{"user_id":"C","recommendation_value":0.3}]}
{"create":{"_id":4}}
{"title":"chair","popularity":0.5,"recommended_for_users":[{"user_id":"A","recommendation_value":0.6},{"user_id":"C","recommendation_value":0.8}]}
{"create":{"_id":5}}
{"title":"shelf","popularity":0.1,"recommended_for_users":[{"user_id":"B","recommendation_value":0.6},{"user_id":"C","recommendation_value":0.5}]}

Query with minimal scripting for the lowest top popularity = 0.3 and user_id = C
GET /product_popularity/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._id,hits.hits._score,hits.hits._source
{
    "query": {
        "dis_max": {
            "queries": [
                {
                    "function_score": {
                        "query": {
                            "range": {
                                "popularity": {
                                    "gte": 0.3
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "field_value_factor": {
                            "field": "popularity",
                            "factor": 1000,
                            "missing": 1
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "recommended_for_users",
                        "query": {
                            "function_score": {
                                "query": {
                                    "term": {
                                        "recommended_for_users.user_id": {
                                            "value": "C"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "field_value_factor": {
                                    "field": "recommended_for_users.recommendation_value",
                                    "factor": 10,
                                    "missing": 1
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "function_score": {
                        "query": {
                            "match_all": {}
                        },
                        "field_value_factor": {
                            "field": "popularity",
                            "factor": 1,
                            "missing": 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

Response
{
    "hits" : {
        "hits" : [
            {
                "_id" : "1",
                "_score" : 800.0,
                "_source" : {
                    "title" : "speaker",
                    "popularity" : 0.8,
                    "recommended_for_users" : [
                        {
                            "user_id" : "A",
                            "recommendation_value" : 0.2
                        },
                        {
                            "user_id" : "B",
                            "recommendation_value" : 0.7
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "_id" : "4",
                "_score" : 500.0,
                "_source" : {
                    "title" : "chair",
                    "popularity" : 0.5,
                    "recommended_for_users" : [
                        {
                            "user_id" : "A",
                            "recommendation_value" : 0.6
                        },
                        {
                            "user_id" : "C",
                            "recommendation_value" : 0.8
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "_id" : "5",
                "_score" : 5.7256613,
                "_source" : {
                    "title" : "shelf",
                    "popularity" : 0.1,
                    "recommended_for_users" : [
                        {
                            "user_id" : "B",
                            "recommendation_value" : 0.6
                        },
                        {
                            "user_id" : "C",
                            "recommendation_value" : 0.5
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "_id" : "3",
                "_score" : 3.435397,
                "_source" : {
                    "title" : "table",
                    "popularity" : 0.2,
                    "recommended_for_users" : [
                        {
                            "user_id" : "B",
                            "recommendation_value" : 0.4
                        },
                        {
                            "user_id" : "C",
                            "recommendation_value" : 0.3
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "_id" : "2",
                "_score" : 0.1,
                "_source" : {
                    "title" : "fridge",
                    "popularity" : 0.1,
                    "recommended_for_users" : [
                        {
                            "user_id" : "A",
                            "recommendation_value" : 0.9
                        },
                        {
                            "user_id" : "B",
                            "recommendation_value" : 0.1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

As you can see the score is differentiate for the top popularity, recommended for user, and other products. You can adjust the factor value in the field_value_factor section
